# format data with NSlog()

Tags: iphone

I am simply logging a number using a for-loop.

```
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{

    NSLog(@"%d",i);
}
```

It prints the number in new line like:

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

But I want to see it formatted on one line like 12345.
How can I do this, any idea?

thanks
Aaryan

Answer (score 9):

`NSLog()` is for logging purposes, not general printing. You want `printf()`.

```
printf("%d", i);
```

will print the number without any extraneous info or newlines added.

Answer (score 3):

You could build up your own string and then output one NSLog at the end:

```
NSMutableString *logString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];
for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
   [logString appendFormat:@"%d" i]
}
NSLog(@"%@", logString);
```

Answer (score 1):

printf("%d",i) is what you need